# R - Add custom packages to cloned version of CRAN

Tags: r, r-package

At my company we have a server where we host, **for internal use only**, a clone of CRAN (refreshed only when new versions of R come out).  We do this to allow internal servers to install packages from R without needing internet access and it helps ensure that everyone at the company is always using the same version of packages (or can easily update to get caught up).

Recently we've been making some custom internal packages.  This tend to be convenience wrapper packages built explicitly around our systems, **they would be of zero use to anyone outside our company** so I don't want to try and submit them to the official CRAN.

How do I 'submit' them to our cloned CRAN so they can be installed via `install.pacakges('blahblah')` instead of me having to email out copies of the packages and upload them to each server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) to inject packages into a repo -- any repo -- and [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) does not care if your repo is a 0% or 100% clone of [CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com), or anywhere in between.

A repo is still just a repo: a collection of source tarballs [and maybe binary packages if you have the (mis)fortune to rely on Windows too] and you simply need to update the PACKAGES files.

We run a local repo at work with our very much non-public packages for the same reason.